# how query between related tables when contains all ids

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

i have 2 related table orders and products,
now i want to find all orders that contains products(2,5,8)
i mean sometimes
i want to find orders that has any of ids,
sometime i want to find orders that have all of ids(and may more)
i use

```
select order.id, product.id, product.name   
from orders 
LEFT JOIN products ON order.id = product.orderId 
where
productId IN (Select value from STRING_SPLIT( @productIdList, ',')
```

and get first case

but i can't get second case
order that covers all idList

Comment: What is the value of `@productIdList`? Why not use a Table Parameter?

Comment: for example 2,5,8, i use comma seperated string

Comment: So, why is what's you have working>?

Comment: Apart from that you have a table called `orders`, and that you keep referencing the keyword `order`, of course. :/

Comment: two related tables, orders and products, each order has one or many product

Comment: That does want answer my question.